# React Magic Move + Gulp Error during build

Tags: reactjs

I am using the yo react-boilerplate scaffold for a simple react project where I hope to test out the magic-move component.

When I run gulp dev I am getting the following error message:

```
Error: Parsing file /Users/Andrew/work/magicmove/node_modules/react-magic-move/modules/components/MagicMove.js: Unexpected token (22:6)
    at Deps.parseDeps (/Users/Andrew/work/magicmove/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:439:28)
    at fromSource (/Users/Andrew/work/magicmove/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:378:44)
    at /Users/Andrew/work/magicmove/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:372:17
    at ConcatStream.<anonymous> (/Users/Andrew/work/magicmove/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/concat-stream/index.js:36:43)
    at ConcatStream.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at finishMaybe (/Users/Andrew/work/magicmove/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:460:14)
    at endWritable (/Users/Andrew/work/magicmove/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:469:3)
    at ConcatStream.Writable.end (/Users/Andrew/work/magicmove/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:436:5)
    at DuplexWrapper.onend (/Users/Andrew/work/magicmove/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:537:10)
    at DuplexWrapper.g (events.js:199:16)
```

I am using a simple require statement like:

var MagicMove = require('react-magic-move');

Any thoughts on where the error is coming from? I'm thinking perhaps it could be a jsx related issue? Do I need something like jsx loader?

Here is the scaffold I am using so that you can look at the gulpfile.. maybe there is something I need to alter here? 
https://github.com/mitchbox/generator-react-boilerplate

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MagicMove.js has a parsing error on line 22.

```
MagicMove.js: Unexpected token (22:6)
```

I would start there.

Probably a jsx error, but it's hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: Thanks .. I think you are right, that is the first line of JSX in the file. MagicMove.js is from the library though, so I am doubtful that it is an actual error there in the code, moreso something on the build side?

Comment: Here is the code:

https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-magic-move/blob/master/modules/components/MagicMove.js

Comment: =( I looked through the code a couple times, and then loaded it up in sublime, and it compiled. Although I would recommend that you consider using getInitialState in your controller-view to call childrenWithPositions(), and putting that data in state. I don't think this is your problem, it's just a best practice imho.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `MagicMove.js` is written in ES6 so you need something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/).

[Babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify) (in case you are using [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)) may help to compile the code.